# HTML compatibility with embedded browsers like Embedded IE and Embedded Mozilla

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, mozilla

My webpage is developed in HTML5, CSS, Bootstrap and JavaScript. Now I need to view my webpage in some embedded browser like embedded IE and Mozilla. The problem is my webpage is not loading properly. Do I need to include any HTML tags in order to make my webpage compatible with embedded browsers? Help me out.

Comment: Does adding the meta tag help you to load your site correctly in the IE browser? If yes, you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: No. The system is actually very old, some POS machines,  which uses older versions of Internet explorer. I guess I'll have to develop code from scratch for these machines.

Comment: Can you please inform us which version of the IE browser you are using for making this test? If possible please try to share some sample code with the picture of the desired output that may help us to understand the issue in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should post any sample code to reproduce the issue. It can give an exact idea about the issue.

I assume that you are using the IE 11 browser and bootstrap 4. I suggest you add the below meta tag in the head section of the web page.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

If `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` is not added in the page then try to add it at the top of the page.

If you are using the older version of the IE browser then you can refer to the [information](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/#internet-explorer) below.

[image]

If the issue still persists and something specific is not working then I suggest you add a sample code here and provide the detailed information about it. We will try to provide further suggestions.